# Download image directly to a photo album

Tags: ios, networking, alamofire, nsurlsession

Currently I'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for network requests. How can I download an image directly to a photo album that already exists using the `PHPhotoLibrary` from `Photos.framework`?

P.S.: I don't mind to have a solution using `NSURLSession` by itself.

**Considerations:** The file can't be stored in disk temporarily. I want the data in memory and save it once into the disk using the `Photos.framework`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out by myself. I implemented it with a `dataTaskWithRequest` from `NSURLSession`.

Initially I thought using the `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` but the `contentsOfURL` method does not return until the entire file is transferred. It should only be used for local files and not for remote ones because if you're loading a large content and the device has a slow connection then the UI will be blocked.

```
// Avoid this!
let originalPhotoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://photo.jpg")!)
```

So, it is possible to load the content into a NSData with a data task. One solution can be like:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString.URLString)!)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
]
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    if let e = error {
        print(e.description)
        return
    }
    guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
        print("No image")
        return
    }
    // Success
    // Note: does not save into an album. I removed that code to be more concise.
    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges {
        let creationRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)
    }, completionHandler: { (success : Bool, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if success == false, let e = error){
            print(e)
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

The data is only available in the final stage but you can instead access the data and see the progress using a session delegate.

```
class Session: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
    var session = NSURLSession()

    var buffer = NSMutableData()
    var expectedContentLength = 0

    override init() {
        super.init()
        session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: queue)
    }

    func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> NSURLSessionDataTask {
        // The delegate is only called if you do not specify a completion block!
        return session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        buffer = NSMutableData()
        expectedContentLength = Int(response.expectedContentLength)
        print("Expected content length:", expectedContentLength)
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Allow)
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
        buffer.appendData(data)
        let percentageDownloaded = Float(buffer.length) / Float(expectedContentLength)
        print("Progress: ", percentageDownloaded)
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        print("Finished with/without error \(error)")
        // Use the buffer to create the UIImage
    }

}
```